# Parallel.ForEach blocking calling method

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, parallel.foreach

I am having a problem with `Parallel.ForEach`. I have written simple application that adds file names to be downloaded to the queue, then using while loop it iterates through the queue, downloads file one at a time, then when file has been downloaded,  another async method is called to create object from downloaded `memoryStream`. Returned result of this method is not awaited, it is discarded, so the next download starts immediately. Everything works fine if I use simple `foreach` in object creation - objects are being created while download is continuing. But if I would like to speed up the object creation process and use `Parallel.ForEach` it stops download process until the object is created. UI is fully responsive, but it just won't download the next object. I don't understand why is this happening - `Parallel.ForEach` is inside `await Task.Run()` and to my limited knowledge about asynchronous programming this should do the trick. Can anyone help me understand why is it blocking first method and how to avoid it?

**Here is a small sample:**

```
public async Task DownloadFromCloud(List<string> constructNames)
{
    _downloadDataQueue = new Queue<string>();
    var _gcsClient = StorageClient.Create();

    foreach (var item in constructNames)
    {
        _downloadDataQueue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    while (_downloadDataQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await _gcsClient.DownloadObjectAsync("companyprojects",
            _downloadDataQueue.Peek(), memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        _ = ReadFileXml(memoryStream);
        _downloadDataQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}

private async Task ReadFileXml(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var reader = new XmlReader();
    var properties = reader.ReadXmlTest(memoryStream);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var entityList = new List<Entity>();
        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            entityList.Add(CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties(item));
        }
        //Parallel.ForEach(properties item =>
        //{
        //    entityList.Add(CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties(item));
        //});
    });
}
```

---

**EDIT**
This is simplified object creation method:

```
public Entity CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties(RebarProperties properties)
{
    var path = new LinearPath(properties.Path);
    var section = new Region(properties.Region);
    var sweep = section.SweepAsMesh(path, 1);
    return sweep;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214132/discussion-on-question-by-niks-parallel-foreach-blocking-calling-method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Returned result of this method is not awaited, it is discarded, so the next download starts immediately.

This is also dangerous. "Fire and forget" means "I don't care when this operation completes, or if it completes. Just discard all exceptions because I don't care." So fire-and-forget *should be* extremely rare in practice. It's not appropriate here.

> UI is fully responsive, but it just won't download the next object.

I have no idea why it would block the downloads, but there's a definite problem in switching to `Parallel.ForEach`: `List<T>.Add` is not threadsafe.

```
private async Task ReadFileXml(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var reader = new XmlReader();
    var properties = reader.ReadXmlTest(memoryStream);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var entityList = new List<Entity>();
        Parallel.ForEach(properties, item =>
        {
            var itemToAdd = CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties(item);
            lock (entityList) { entityList.Add(itemToAdd); }
        });
    });
}
```

One tip: if you have a result value, `PLINQ` is often cleaner than `Parallel`:

```
private async Task ReadFileXml(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var reader = new XmlReader();
    var properties = reader.ReadXmlTest(memoryStream);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var entityList = proeprties
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties)
            .ToList();
    });
}
```

However, the code still suffers from the fire-and-forget problem.

For a better fix, I'd recommend taking a step back and using something more suited to "pipeline"-style processing. E.g., TPL Dataflow:

```
public async Task DownloadFromCloud(List<string> constructNames)
{
  // Set up the pipeline.
  var gcsClient = StorageClient.Create();
  var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<string, MemoryStream>(async constructName =>
  {
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await gcsClient.DownloadObjectAsync("companyprojects", constructName, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    return memoryStream;
  });
  var processBlock = new TransformBlock<MemoryStream, List<Entity>>(memoryStream =>
  {
    var reader = new XmlReader();
    var properties = reader.ReadXmlTest(memoryStream);
    return proeprties
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(CreateObjectsFromDownloadedProperties)
        .ToList();
  });
  var resultsBlock = new ActionBlock<List<Entity>>(entities => { /* TODO */ });
  downloadBlock.LinkTo(processBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
  processBlock.LinkTo(resultsBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

  // Push data into the pipeline.
  foreach (var constructName in constructNames)
    await downloadBlock.SendAsync(constructName);
  downlodBlock.Complete();

  // Wait for pipeline to complete.
  await resultsBlock.Completion;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have tested it, and it seems that each `processBlock` is fired only when previous `processBlock` has completed.  I found that I can use `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` to set how many messages can be processed by block concurrently, but in case if I have used for example `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10` the larger the number of items that have to be processed, the longer overall time it takes to reach `Completion` which is interesting because I thought the more parallel operations the better/faster my code will run. Could you please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Probably because it's already parallel: the `processBlock` is doing `AsParallel` *inside* the block. You probably don't want to do both; either choose parallel processing inside the block (i.e., the code in my answer), or parallelize the block itself (i.e., remove `.AsParallel()` and add `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`). You want to do parallel inside the block if each file has lots of objects and you want to process one file at a time; you want to parallelize the block if files can have few objects and you want to process multiple files at a time.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I have one more question - where should I generally deal with exceptions using this TPL pipeline approach?  To me it seems that a good place would be inside each block so I can catch specific exceptions, register faulty items and react accordingly. But I can easily think of some scenarios where I would need to abort the whole pipeline. I could simply re-throw `Exception`, but from inside of the block I can't register how many of items have already been processed and then if I re-catch `Exception` outside `TransformationBlock`, it has already been cleaned.

Comment: There's a couple of approaches. If you want to fault the block, let the exception escape the block lambda. It will fault and the fault will flow down to `Completion`. Another approach is "railway programming", where each block actually works with a `(T, Exception)` pair so that exceptions flow through the pipeline just like regular data. If you're interested in the railway approach, I have a [Try](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Try) library designed for that.

Comment: I could of course register completed items in `resultsBlock` and then in case of `Exception` simply just check, but I would like to know if there is some generally approved method for situations like this.

Comment: And if I fault the `downloadBlock` in the middle of operation, is the previously downloaded item that is at the same time being processed in `processBlock` guaranteed to finish before "escaped" `Exception` is catched in `Completion`?

Comment: No, a faulting block is considered "catastrophic". It tears down the current block and (because we're propagating completion) also propagates the fault to its linked blocks downstream. When a block faults, it discards all its buffers and refuses new input.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more thing - here's a scenario - user pushes data into pipeline, and while it is processing decides to add more data. I'd like to use the same pipeline, so I have moved `downloadBlock.Complete()` inside last `resultBlock` and it gets set when total file count equals finished file count. At this point pipeline is finally shut, but every additional bit of data pushed into it before reaching this point is processed. This works, but I would like to ask if such use is considered good practice and if there are any underwater stones that I should be aware of with this approach?

Comment: The problem with self-completing pipelines is that it can be difficult for the producing code to know if the pipeline is still usable or not.

Comment: I see. Thank you for answering! You have been tremendously helpful! Even though your answer doesn't directly answer my question, I have completely changed my code based on your recommendations and I am very satisfied how it works!